# XML Parser is not failing while parsing String xml with special character > but fails with < in JAVA

Tags: xml-parsing, special-characters, w3c

We are converting the XML message to string and parsing it using XML parser. The special characters `<` `>` are sent to us as `&lt;` and `&gt;`. However somehow `&gt;` is getting converted to `>` at our end. The parser does not fail in this case and totally ignores the `>` symbol.

However when I manually converted `&lt;` to `<` the parser fails with org.xml.sax.SAXParseException.
I read on one blog that for text only `>` `&` are considered special characters. At our host system, they are converting String to  org.w3c.dom.Document format. So same rule will be applied for org.w3c.dom.Document format as well?

Help in providing more details on this will be appreciated.